# How to transform fractional coordinates into cartesian?

Tags: python

I need to make this transformation because I need to grow up my unit cell using a code with Python. But, I'm studying it yet and I need some help.

Comment: Are you asking for the relevant formulas, or do you already have the formulas at hand but are just asking how to code them?

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/periodic-boundary-conditions-for-triclinic-box/20995#20995 might be of use

Comment: Perhaps with the fractional coordinates you could create a file which can be opened by VESTA(Like POSCAR for VASP) this shouldn't be that hard to do considering you already have the coordinates and then you could go to File > Export data and then save in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://www.ruppweb.org/Xray/tutorial/Coordinate%20system%20transformation.htm)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly your question, you have the fractional coordinates of the atoms in the unit cell, and (I'm assuming) that you also have the unitcell (or supercell) vectors. In this case the transformation is quite simply a basis-change transformation.

To illustrate this, let's assume that the cartesian cell vectors are given by:
$$\left(\matrix{\vec{a}\\\vec{b}\\\vec{c}}\right) = \left( \matrix{a_1&a_2&a_3 \\ b_1&b_2&b_3 \\ c_1&c_2&c_3} \right)$$

And the fractional coordinates of an atom given by:
$$\vec{x}=\left( \matrix{x_1,x_2,x_3}\right)$$

Then the cartesian coordinate vector $X$ for the atom is just:
$$ \vec{x} \bullet \left(\matrix{\vec{a}\\\vec{b}\\\vec{c}}\right) = x_1\vec{a}+x_2\vec{b}+x_3\vec{c}$$

This can be implemented easily with the `numpy` (imported as `np` below) `dot()` function:

```
cvec #= 3 by 3 matrix of unit cell vectors (each vector in a row)
fracAtomCoords #= natom by 3 matrix of fractional atom coordinates (each atom in a row)
cartAtomCoords = np.dot(fracAtomCoords, cvec) # natom by 3 matrix of cartesian atom coorodinates (each atom in a row)
```